# PySide: How to append text from different classes in QTextBrowser?

Tags: python-3.x, qt4, pyside

I have a little application to run some commands and redirect the output in a QTextBrowser. It works fine when I'm using the buttons and command line in the console widget. But a want to use buttons in the side widgest, too. When I'm calling the function from the side widget it runs the command but I don't get a output in the QTextBrowser.

See a little example of the code below. Thanks a lot.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)

        # Add the Graphics widget
        self.graphicsViewWidget = GraphicsViewWidget(self)
        self.graphicsScene = self.graphicsViewWidget.scene()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.graphicsViewWidget)

        # Create side widget
        self.sideDock = QtGui.QDockWidget()
        self.sideDock.setAllowedAreas(QtCore.Qt.RightDockWidgetArea | QtCore.Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea)
        self.sideDock.setWindowTitle("SideWidget")
        self.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea, self.sideDock)
        self.sideWidget = SideWidget(self)
        self.sideDock.setWidget(self.sideWidget)

        # Create console widget
        self.consoleDock = QtGui.QDockWidget()
        self.consoleDock.setAllowedAreas(QtCore.Qt.RightDockWidgetArea | QtCore.Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea)
        self.consoleDock.setWindowTitle("Console")
        self.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.BottomDockWidgetArea, self.consoleDock)
        self.consoleWidget = ConsoleWidget(self)
        self.consoleDock.setWidget(self.consoleWidget)

        # Create menu
        fileMenu = self.menuBar().addMenu("&File")
        fileMenu.addAction(QtGui.QAction("&Quit...", self, shortcut="Ctrl+Q", triggered=self.close))

class GraphicsViewWidget(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QGraphicsView.__init__(self, parent)


class SideWidget(QtGui.QWidget, ):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)

        # Buttons
        self.execute_button = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.execute_button.setText('Execute')
        self.execute_button.setFixedHeight(25)

        # Add Buttons to widget
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.execute_button)

        # Button actions
        self.execute_button.pressed.connect(self.execute_button_pressed)

    def execute_button_pressed(self):
        print('execute_button_pressed')

        ##########################################
        # want to run commands from here
        ##########################################

        cnsl=ConsoleWidget()
        cnsl.run_command()



        cnsl=RunCommands(self)
        cnsl.run_command()


        #RunCommands(self)




class ConsoleWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)

        # label
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel('Command Line', self)

        # commandline
        self.commandline = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.commandline.setFixedHeight(25)
        self.commandline.setToolTip('Run commands here')

        # The upper layout holds label and commandline
        upperLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        upperLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        upperLayout.addWidget(self.commandline)

        # buttons
        self.dummy_button = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.dummy_button.setText('Run Dummy')
        self.dummy_button.setToolTip('For testing')
        self.dummy_button.setFixedHeight(25)

        # Textbrowser
        #self.textbrowser = QtGui.QTextBrowser(self)
        self.textbrowser = QtGui.QTextEdit(self) # for typing in

        # The lower layout holds the textbrowser
        lowerLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        lowerLayout.addWidget(self.dummy_button)
        lowerLayout.addWidget(self.textbrowser)

        # Add layouts to mainlayout
        self.mainLayout.addLayout(upperLayout)
        self.mainLayout.addLayout(lowerLayout)
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)

        # Button actions
        self.dummy_button.clicked.connect(self.run_command)
        self.commandline.returnPressed.connect(self.run_commandline)


    def run_command(self):

        print('run_command')
        command='cmd.exe /c echo test'
        print('Self   ',self)
        print('Command',command)

        self.textbrowser.append('test')

        # err and out
        ##self.runner.readyReadStandardError.connect(self.ErrInfo)
        ##self.runner.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.OutInfo)

        # Run command
        ##self.runner.start(command)

    def run_commandline(self):

        command_text = str(self.commandline.text())

        self.runner = QtCore.QProcess()

        # Make sure newInfo gets all output
        self.runner.readyReadStandardError.connect(self.ErrInfo)
        self.runner.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.OutInfo)

        # Run the command
        command='cmd.exe /c ' + command_text
        #print(command)
        self.runner.start(command)

        # clearing commandline
        self.commandline.clear()

    def ErrInfo(self):
        errString = str(self.runner.readAllStandardError())
        print('errString', errString, end=" ")
        self.textbrowser.append(errString)

    def OutInfo(self):
        outString = str(self.runner.readAllStandardOutput())
        print('outString', outString, end=" ")

        #cnsl=ConsoleWidget()

        self.textbrowser.append(outString)

class RunCommands(QtGui.QTextBrowser):
    def __init__(self, parent):

        print('RunCommands')
        QtGui.QTextBrowser.__init__(self, parent)

        # Textbrowser
        #self.textbrowser = ConsoleWidget().textbrowser
        self.run_command()

        #self.textbrowser.append('test2')

    def run_command(self):

        print('run_command')
        command='cmd.exe /c echo test'
        command='cmd.exe /c notepad'
        print('Self   ',self)
        print('Command',command)

        ConsoleWidget().textbrowser.append('test2')

        self.runner = QtCore.QProcess(self)

        # err and out
        self.runner.readyReadStandardError.connect(self.ErrInfo)
        self.runner.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.OutInfo)

        # Run command
        self.runner.start(command)


    def run_commandline(self):

        command_text = str(self.commandline.text())

        self.runner = QtCore.QProcess()

        # err and out
        self.runner.readyReadStandardError.connect(self.ErrInfo)
        self.runner.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.OutInfo)

        # Run command
        command='cmd.exe /c ' + command_text
        #print(command)
        self.runner.start(command)

        # clearing commandline
        self.commandline.clear()

    def ErrInfo(self):
        errString = str(self.runner.readAllStandardError())
        print('errString', errString, end=" ")
        self.textbrowser.append(errString)

    def OutInfo(self):
        outString = str(self.runner.readAllStandardOutput())
        print('outString', outString, end=" ")
        self.textbrowser.append(outString)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a question of where do you create your widget and how to access them.

You have a `MainWindow` which has two child widgets: a `sideWidget` and a `consoleWidget`. 
Then, in the `SideWidget.execute_button_pressed`, you create **another** `ConsoleWidget`. This new widget is nowhere in your layout, so you just don't see it.

To connect the input of `MainWindow.sideWidget` (button clicked) to the output of `MainWindow.consoleWidget` (run a command and print text), you simply have to do it in the class `MainWindow`.
Something like this:

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        ...
        self.sideWidget.execute_button.clicked.connect(self.execute)
        ...

    def execute_function(self):
        print('execute_button_pressed')
        self.consoleWidget.run_command()
```

Or just in one line:

```
self.sideWidget.execute_button.clicked.connect(self.consoleWidget.run_command)
```